# Execution of method with intervals

Tags: java, jsp

I have a page and I have two execute methods which writes data into tables.

I would like to add a delay of 5 minutes between two methods in JSP. i.e. second method should execute only after 5 minutes.

How can I do this in JSP?

Thanks

Comment: you can use Thread.sleep(5*60*1000) in first method.

Comment: @Quoi So after `statement.executeQuery(sql); Thread.sleep(5*60*1000);` then call the second `statement.executeQuery(sql2);` ?

Comment: Why do this in a JSP, why, why?

Comment: @FrankPavageau yes good question, this is very old system and management doesn't want to change or make it better. Only doing the patch up work and hence no other choice.

Comment: yes you can. are you sharing the dbconnection in two method?

Comment: @Quoi Yes I am sharing dbconnection in two methods. When I tried `statement.executeQuery(sql); Thread.sleep(5*60*1000); statement.executeQuery(sql2);` page doesn't submit it just stays.

Comment: @Polppan - If your Thread sleep time exceeds the interactive_timeout then it'll create error. you can increase the interactive_timeout or you can close the connection and open again in second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do it in a JSP, you can indeed use a `Thread.sleep()` call, but you'll have to make sure the request is a POST if you need the output, as a GET will probably seen as a timeout by the caller if it takes 5 minutes to complete. It's also ugly as hell, and will block a thread in the connector pool.

You could also submit a `Runnable` or `Callable` to a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) if you don't need the result of the second method to answer the request.

Comment: Frank like you said I need the result of second method the complete the request. I have put a interval of one minute and jsp page stays one minute to complete the second execution.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your explanation as I do not have much choice.

Comment: Frank to check with you, if the database insertion was in a java bean then this problem of delay in page submit could have avoided isn't it?

Comment: @Polppan not specifically a Java _bean_, but if it was invoked asynchronously through another object **and** you didn't need the result to display the page, yes, the delay could be avoided.

Comment: Frank I managed to move the database insertion from jsp to a stored procedure. I am having a `DBMS_LOCK.sleep()` for one minute between two inserts. However my form is stays for one minute till the insertion completes. How can I resolve this issue having able to move the insertion part to database. Thanks

Comment: @Polppan Since the statement execution won't return until the queries are completed on the DB side, it's still a blocking call from the JSP, but now you also block a DB connection while blocking the thread, when there might have been 2 distinct connections before. The only way for your request to return immediately is if the delay and second insertion (whether the delay is managed on the Java side or on the DB side) are done asynchronously, which means you cannot use the result. Cf. the point about the `Executor` in my answer.